# st_combine and st_union produce empty attribute table for shapefile (how to edit before st_write?)

Tags: shapefile, r, attribute-table, ogr, sf

I am starting with R programming and I am having a hard time figuring out how to edit the attribute table of a shapefile after using `st_combine` and `st_union`.

My shapefile has multiple polygons and I want to create a shapefile with a unique outline and a well-defined attribute table like this one:

```
| A | B | C |
|---|---|---|
| X | Y | Z |
```

This is part of my code:

```
# Combining features into one
Shapefile <- st_read(Shapefile2Process)
st_combine(Shapefile)
Outline <- st_union(Shapefile)

# Simplification depending on TolInMeters. 
Outlinetol <- st_simplify(Outline, preserveTopology = FALSE, dTolerance = TolInMeters)

# Save new shapefile with outline feature
st_write(Outlinetol, NewShapefile)
```

`print(names(Outlinetol))` returns `NULL`, the shapefile is created.

I want to add columns with values to the empty attribute table but I don't know if this is possible with a sf object and before `st_write`, and how to do it?

I tried to convert this sf object to a `"Spatial"` object using `as(Outlinetol, "Spatial")`, create `Outlinetol$A <- "X"` and then `writeOGR(Outlinetol,NewShapefile,driver="ESRI Shapefile")` but I was not successful...

Answer (score 0):

I used `Outline <- st_as_sf(Outline)` to convert from sfc polygon to sf object.

Now, this works:

```
Outline$A <- "X" 

Outline$B <- "Y" 

Outline$C <- "Z"
```

And I can edit the attribute table.